# Constant in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

Is using a constant in the global.asax a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

It's always go to, **what are you holding in such variable?**

I keep my main settings (**READ ONLY**) variables in my `web.config` file in the `<appSettings>` area, for example:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="AmazonS3:CalendarPath" 
        value="http://mycloud.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Calendar/" />
</appSettings>
```

and access such values with

```
string calPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AmazonS3:CalendarPath"];
```

Either in my Views or Controllers.

**This is a lovely place to hold your read-only variables** as, no mater if your web application is built or not, compiled or showing all source files, you can easily change the variable to what you need, without opening a compiled file, change it and compile the project again... saves a lot of trouble and gives a certain dynamic to the hole application settings.

---

If by other hand you want a **READ/WRITE** way of saving variables across your application, you have 3 ways, all with pros and cons

1. **Use Session State to save the variables** This is the most used, but it's terrible on Cloud Platforms as the request can change servers and the new server that received the continue request of the user, does not have the session
2. **Use Cookies to save user variables** Cookies can be modified on the fly by the user, so we only use this to save settings that are minor changes, like UI definitions.
3. **Use a Cache Layer to hold the variables** This is the most used in Cloud Platforms as not only you can save settings, but you can also save portions of data that you access most of the time.

There is also the *[Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1)* on `global.asax` witch was very used back the Classic ASP days, since then I never have used them as they have the same flow as the Session Variables, witch are placed in memory... any Application Pool reset, any new build, all session are lost.

There are also, plenty of posts that you ca search to have a better knowledge of all options you have to save variables cross application on your ASP.NET project.

Comment: dear your answer is really informative but my question was about constant not vairable

Comment: so, what's a constant? it's a variable that is constant throughout the life of the application ... same as read only variables! the real name of a constant is "constant variable", you're messing up somewhere! `public static const string USER_NAME = "abc";` is a constant variable, variable is the `USER_NAME` part!